# How to read special characters from a text file?

Tags: c

I have a text file with some special characters (`\n`, `\t`, etc). The question is: is there anyway to print a new line or a tab instead just printing the string `\n` or `\t`?

```
int main(){

    char line[10];

    FILE*file= fopen("file.txt", "r"); // txt content => "line 1 \n line 2 \n line 3"
    if (file != NULL){
        while (fgets(line, 10, file) != NULL)
            printf("%s", line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fgets` preserves all the characters that were in the file. So each line read into a string still ends in newline `\n` and any tab `\t` found remains there too.

Comment: So your file actually contains literal backslashes, and you want to translate those escape sequences into the corresponding characters?

Comment: You need to search for the backslashes, then get the next character after it. You can then use a `switch()` statement to output the appropriate translation.

Comment: You can use `strchr()` to search for the backslashes.

Answer (score -1):

Call this function:

```
void cleanUp(char * line) {
    int x;
    int y = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < strlen(line) - 1; x++) {
        if (line[x] == '\\') {
            if (line[x + 1] == 'n') {
                line[y++] = '\n';
                x = x + 2; /* if there is always a space after the \n otherwise x++ */
                continue;
            }
            if (line[x + 1] == 't') {
                line[y++] = '\t';
                x = x + 2; /* if there is always a space after the \t otherwise x++ */
                continue;
            }
        }
        line[y++] = line[x];
    }
    line[y++] = '\n';
    line[y] = '\0';
}
```

before printing *line*.

Comment: If `line == "\\tx"`, this result in `"\t\n"`.   `x` is lost.